# Object is not being rendered

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

I got this project where one object is not being rendered. I already cleared all restrict render, made sure that it is enabled in the render and moved everything from my second collection to my first.

.blend file here:

[image]

[image: Look Dev]

[image: Rendered]

[image: Rendered with selected object]

Comment: .blend would be nice to help with solving the problem

Comment: Welcome, Red. You may use this link to send your .blend files: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: uploaded the file :)

Comment: you don't need to say "edited" in the post :) Check [ask] to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

Alpha is set to zero in the material:

[image]

This is not visible in preview as Eevee needs to change the material setting to alpha to be transparent (this is not the case for Cycles).

Comment: Oh wow that worked, thank you very much. I dont know how this happened, I did not do anything besides giving it a dark color :)